# Domain name regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find if a string has valid domain names or not in JavaScript.
As per requirement, these are my valid and invalid domain names.

### Valid Domain:

- api.google.com
- *.api.google.com
- *.api.google.user.com
- tenant.my.centrify-kibble.net
- aws.logs.security.stark.tony.com
- myest.r-project.org
- login-dev.qacloudad.com

### Invalid Domain:

- https://google.com
- https://www.google.com
- https://*.google.com
- *.google.com/
- *google.com/
- *google.com
- *google.com.*
- login-dev.qacloudad.com.
- login-dev.qacloudad.com.*
- .login-dev.qacloudad.com

below code is working as expected for both valid as well as invalid domain except "*google.com".
I am still getting valid expression as result for "*google.com"

How can I fix this RegEx?

```js
var fqdn = "aws.logs.security.stark.tony.com";
if (fqdn.match("^(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-*]+([\\-\\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$")) {
    console.log("Matched");
}
else{
    console.log("Not Matched");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?:\*\.)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oPKl2a/2)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` - Beginning of string.
- `(?:\*\.)?` - Match an optional "*." literally.
- `[a-z0-9]+` - One or more alphanumeric characters.
- `(?:[\-.][a-z0-9]+)*` - A hyphen or a dot followed by one or more alphanumeric characters to be matched zero or more times.
- `\.[a-z]{2,6}` - A dot followed by between two and six letters.
- `$` - End of string.

**JavaScript test:**

```js
var fqdn = "aws.logs.security.stark.tony.com";
if (fqdn.match(/^(?:\*\.)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/)) {
    console.log("Matched");
}
else{
    console.log("Not Matched");
}
```

To support upper-case letters, you can either (re-)add `A-Z` to the character classes or simply append the `i` flag at the end:

```
fqdn.match(/^(?:\*\.)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i)
//                                                              ^
```

Comment: this helps to fix the issue.